# Can an even function ever be injective?

Tags: solution-verification

In the first few lessons of an introductory Calculus class, there is this exercise:

> We say that a function $f$: $R → R$ is even if $f(−x) = f(x)$. Can an even function ever be injective?

My proof is as follows and I am wondering if it is correct:

let $y=-x$
$f(y)=f(x)$
$y\neq x$
$\therefore$ No, an even function can never be injective

Comment: As long as you choose $y = -x \neq 0$, you're all good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. Since $f(1) = f(-1)$ does not imply $1=-1$, as an example, the function is not injective.